# Cat keeps meowing to go in forbidden room

Tags: cats

There is a room in my house where I do my carpentry work. That room is full of dust and wood debris and I don't want my cat to go in there because I don't want it to come out dusty and I am afraid it could get hurt on the sharp objects in there. So I keep the door shut.

The problem is that my cat would oftenly sit in front of that door and start meowing for hours and will only stop if I let it in. It does that no matter if I am in the room or not. How can I make it forget about wanting to go in that room?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cats are highly inquistive by nature, as you seem to have found out and often won't let an idea 'go' until they find something more interesting to investigate.

I'd suggest try putting a simple cardboard box (only just large enough for the cat if possible) by the door and you may find the cat is happy enough to sit in this box, instead of trying to get into the room.

If this doesn't work, you could try leaving some toys near the door, which you can use to play with the cat if they start meowing, to distract them - however be aware you may cause them to associate meowing at this door, with being played with! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I can't guarantee you that once you open that door, that your cat won't want to go in and play around but the main issue here is exacly that, the door that is always shut. The cat knows that there's a barrier there, that they're not allowed in there and they want to be. They're curious and they like to be in charge. They want to see what super misterious and cool thing you could possibly be hidding from them behind that door.

Personally, it has happened to me many times with my cat. I open the door, he looks around and leaves.

I suggest either letting the cat in occasionally (under supervision or on your lap) or to try and distract him with things that could interest him more. Now, it depends on cat to cat, but, usually, cardboxes are a winner between felines.

The fact that it is a room where you do carpentry work makes me believe that it triggers your cat's senses a lot, making him curious/adventurous (because of smells, per instance).

Answer (score 0):

A lot can depend on the cat, but you might try carrying your cat into the room to show them around. Often being there once and seeing what is in there will reduce the cat's desire to go there.  The space will seem less mysterious and interesting (or possibly threatening) to the cat, so it will meow less to go in.